# Python Selenium Time Out Exception

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction, try-except

I am working on data scraping project. I am using below Try and Except code block to load url.

```
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Page Loading Failed......")
    print("Trying by Refreshing...")
    for number_of_try in range(1,9):
        print("Number of try ",number_of_try)
        try:
            driver.refresh()
            break
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Fail")
            print("trying after 1 miunutes")
            time.sleep(60)
```

Issue here is, code is not going to **Except block** when I get **TimeoutException**. I am not getting why is this happening.

Here is my Exception Error:

> TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000

Comment: Are you want to try to get page load 8 times, and if this fails to do so raise an Exception, right?

Comment: @VictorErmakov No, I want to load page only one time. But if I got Timeout Exception I want to go to Except part and then again I will check page load

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it - Recursion.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

TRY_LIMIT = 10
SLEEP_TIMER = 60


def get_url(driver, url, try_number=1):
    if try_number > TRY_LIMIT:
        return None # or you can raise other exception
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIMER)
        get_url(driver, url, try_number+1)
```

and use it like this

```
get_url(driver,url)
```